# Spring, Java - run many scheduled-tasks in parallel

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, executor

I try to run many scheduled-tasks in parallel with scheduler, but only one starts.
my beans configuration in spring-scheduler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5"/>
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>

    <bean id="UpdateScheduler" class="org.ws.scheduled.UpdateScheduler" />
    <bean id="PatchData" class="org.ws.scheduled.PatchData" />

    <task:scheduled-tasks> 
        <task:scheduled ref="UpdateScheduler" method="start" fixed-delay="1000" />
        <task:scheduled ref="PatchData" method="start" fixed-delay="5000" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler" executor="executor" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Which are you using, you are mixing annotations and XML the latter doesn't know anything about your configured scheduler and executor.

Comment: can you write the example , please !

Comment: You need to wire your scheduler and executor to your `<task:scheduled-tasks>` currently it will create another scheduler/executor to run.

Comment: use quartz Scheduler for  parallel tasks

Comment: @umapathi you don't need quartz for parallel execution.

Comment: Hi, I want to configure many task for parallel execution without quartz, can you write example, please.

Comment: @prilia the answer is already in the comments... Wire the scheduler and executor to your `<task:scheduled-tasks>`. See also https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-task-namespace-scheduled-tasks

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum which one is best for parallel task execution

Comment: I'm not going to answer that as that is highly opinionated.

Comment: I configure task like this  <task:scheduled ref="UpdateJsonData" method="updateJsonData" fixed-rate="1000"/> and there is many instancesstarted while the first not finished. Is it possible to configure only one task run in same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all !
I started to use with this config and it's working fine from here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-task-namespace-scheduled-tasks

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="methodA" fixed-delay="5000" initial-delay="1000"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="beanB" method="methodB" fixed-rate="5000"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="beanC" method="methodC" cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI"/>
```